# Howto enable only one plugin to test?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-system

I need to test a vim plugin. The problem: I already have my vim setup in current env, so `~/.vimrc` is occupied.

I want to issue a command like `vim -u <blah..blah>` that maybe specifies the plugin path and has some other options to enable testing the plugin only.

Answer (score 4):

A general recommendation when debugging an issue is to start vim with `-u NONE`, which skips all initialization.

If you just want to start vim without plugins and with a custom .vimrc file start vim with the following command:

```
vim --noplugin -u <test_vimrc_file> <your_file_name>
```

then issue the command `:packadd <package_name>` to load the plugin you want to test.

Comment: Nice, but assume I have minimal vimrc, how to add `packadd <package_name>` in it to load only one plugin when start with minimal vimrc `vim -u minimal-vimrc`. I tried but it always load all in `~/.vim/pack/default/start`, I get minimal-vimdc from here: https://gist.github.com/r00k/8fc7e4e9d35ccbfb64aa

Comment: Use the `vim --noplugin -u .minimal_vimrc`. See `:help load-plugins` for details.

Comment: [Update: I've added it to my answer, since it answers better your original question.]

Comment: This doesn't work for plugins stored under `/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin`, where many plugins are stored. How do I add this directory to the packpath?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
set rtp-=~/.vim
set rtp-=~/.vim/after
set rtp^=/path/to/some-plugin
set rtp+=/path/to/some-plugin/after

set vif=NONE
filetype plugin indent on
syntax enable
```

Write the code in a file, e.g. `/tmp/vimrc`, then start Vim with this shell command:

```
vim -Nu /tmp/vimrc
```

The `-u` argument specifies the path to a custom vimrc, while the `-N` argument resets `'compatible'`.
`-N` is necessary, because:

1. you probably don't want `'compatible'` to be set
2. when you pass any value different than `DEFAULTS` to `-u`, `'compatible'` is set

See `:h -u` and `:h -N`.

Note that `'compatible'` is always disabled in Nvim (see `:h nvim-defaults`), so you don't need `-N` for the latter:

```
nvim -u /tmp/vimrc
```

---

If the plugin you're testing doesn't contain an `after/` directory, you can remove this line:

```
set rtp+=/path/to/some-plugin/after
```

Setting `'viminfofile'` to `NONE` makes sure your viminfo file is not read; the contents of the latter could interfere while you're testing your plugin.

Note that in Nvim, `'viminfofile'` is deprecated in favor of `'shadafile'`; if you use it, replace `set vif=NONE`, with `set sdf=NONE`.

Also, if you use Nvim, you may be interested in making `'guicursor'` empty:

```
set gcr=
```

Because Nvim sets `'guicursor'` by default ([even with `-u NONE`](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/6778#issuecomment-302945056)), which makes it send escape sequences to set the shape of the cursor; these sequences may not always be correctly understood by your terminal, and may interfere while you're testing your plugin.

---

If for some reason, you need some of your plugins to be sourced (matching `~/.vim/plugin/**/*.vim` or `~/.vim/after/plugin/**/*.vim`), try this instead:

```
set rtp-=~/.vim
set rtp-=~/.vim/after
set rtp^=/path/to/some-plugin
set rtp+=/path/to/some-plugin/after
set rtp^=~/.vim
set rtp+=~/.vim/after

set vif=NONE
filetype plugin indent on
syntax enable
```

---

If your plugin doesn't need:

- syntax scripts, remove `syntax enable`
- indent scripts, remove `indent` in `filetype plugin indent on`
- filetype scripts, remove `plugin` in `filetype plugin indent on`
- any of the above, remove the lines `filetype plugin indent on` and `syntax enable`

---

If you use [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips), you could try this snippet:

```
snippet vimrc "Minimal vimrc to test a plugin" bm
set rtp-=~/.vim
set rtp-=~/.vim/after
set rtp^=${1:~/.vim/plugged/vim-${2:foo}}${3:
set rtp+=$1/after}${4:
set rtp^=~/.vim}${5:
set rtp+=~/.vim/after}

${6:set `!v has('nvim') ? 'sdf=NONE gcr=' : 'vif=NONE'`
}${7:filetype plugin indent on
syntax enable}

$0
endsnippet
```

Some of the paths which are used in the `set rtp` settings assume you're using [`vim-plug`](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) as a plugin manager; if that's not the case, you'll need to edit this line:

```
set rtp^=${1:~/.vim/plugged/vim-${2:foo}}${3:
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So that the path points to the directory of your plugin.

Comment: This answer shows how to create the requisite vimrc, but not the invocation of vim that would trigger it’s behavior.